# Ruby Factory Method - what is wrong?

Tags: ruby, methods, factory

So I copied this code from a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9OySOWLYIg

He ran it in his video no problem, but when I run it, it gives me an error

C:/rails/11.rb:17:in `create': Unknown hero (RuntimeError)
        from C:/rails/11.rb:6:in`block in initialize'
        from C:/rails/11.rb:6:in `times'
        from C:/rails/11.rb:6:in`initialize'
        from C:/rails/11.rb:22:in `new'
        from C:/rails/11.rb:22:in`'

---

```
class Party
    attr_reader :members

    def initialize(number, occupation)
        @members = []
        number.times { members << create(occupation)}
    end
end

class PartyFactory < Party
    def create(occupation)
        if occupation == :warrior
            Warrior.new
        elseif occupation == :mage
            Mage.new
        else
            raise "Unknown hero"
        end
    end
end

party = PartyFactory.new(2, :mage)
```

Another question I have is what if intead of  Mage.new , I do Mage.new("fred"), to set the name for mage, where does the "fred" part end up?

Sorry, I am very new to Ruby and can not find a working example to understand how to set up factory methods.

Comment: For basic ruby questions, you might like [Programming Ruby: 4th edition](https://pragprog.com/book/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0) or the first edition of which is free online: http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `elseif` to `elsif` (without the second e).

Then make sure to initialize `Mage` and `Warrior` classes as you'll get a `NameError` if you don't.

Comment: Thank you. I made the changes and it worked. Now I get another error after making the following updates